# Can't get C# for loop going in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, for-loop

I was given the following task in a C# Beginner's course:

> *Write a program that prints the first 10 members of the sequence: 2, -3, 4, -5, 6, -7, …*

I wrote the following program, but it only prints the digit `2` to the Visual Studio console, nothing else.

Is it something wrong with the `for loop` or it's something else?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SandBox
{
    class Exercise
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int printToConsole;
            for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0)   
                    printToConsole = i;
                else
                    printToConsole = i * (-1);

                Console.WriteLine(printToConsole);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried pressing a Button?   `Console.ReadKey();`waits for an input to continue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to delete (*or move outside of loop*) `Console.ReadKey()` like. It expects to put some key to pass from that line.

From [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey.aspx);

> The `ReadKey` method **waits**, that is, blocks on the thread issuing the
>   `ReadKey` method, **until** a character or function key is pressed.

If you delete, it prints;

```
2
-3
4
-5
6
-7
8
-9
10
```

But this prints `9` element. If you want `10` element, you need to change your condition of for loop as `i <= 11`.

Answer (score 1):

Move the

```
Console.ReadKey()
```

outside of the loop :)